# set<class> insert problem

Tags: c++

why is the following programm not working?
How can i fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class K {

private:
    long a;
};

int main ()
{   
    K a;
    set<K> b;

    b.insert(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific – mention the error message and error location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) requires a sorting of the elements. It requires that you can compare its elements according to some ordering.

Either add an `operator <` for your class `K` or provide the second template argument – the comparer – to the `set` class that determines the ordering between two `K` instances.

Overloading the `operator <` is straightforward:

```
bool operator <(K const& x, K const& y) {
     return x.a < y.a;
}
```

This will mean that one instance of `K` is less than another if and only if its member `a` is less than the other’s.

Answer (score 0):

set requires your class to have operator< defined. For example:

```
class K {
public:

bool operator< (const K& other) const {
    return this->a < other.a;
}

private:

long a;

};
```